# AWS Glue executor memory limit showing error ambiguous option: --conf could match

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

My glue job is getting "Failed due to put of memory"

I have gone through the link [AWS Glue executor memory limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49034126/aws-glue-executor-memory-limit)

I have added

- Key: --conf
- Value: spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=7g

I have one environment variable :(key) --dynamodb , (value) sample-table

- I got below error  "ambiguous option: --conf could match --dynamodb"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dkSNC.png

Comment: Can you add the stack trace to your question. Is it driver or executor going OOM ? Also have you tried larger instance types ?

Comment: @PrabhakarReddy its driver , don't know to do larger instance types

Comment: From the image attached it looks like you are running python shell job and not Glue ETL? If yes then there will not be an executor or driver